# How to detect Digital Screen noise in images? (Images captured from Digital Screen)?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect the Noise in images for which images are captured from the Computer / Mobile or TC screen. and these are the few examples of Images

[image]

[image]

[image]

What should bethe approach to this? Can we use the [FFT](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/backgroundfastfouriertransform.html) or any other Spatial filters like [Laplace](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Laplacian%20is%20a%202,see%20zero%20crossing%20edge%20detectors) or Sobel and see the Standard Deviation / Variation / Mean of that image? I do not have any idea where to start. Can someone please refer me to a code, solution, paper, blog  of this kind?

Comment: maybe ask on [OpenCV forum](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: that isn't noise. you are asking about [moiré patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern). you must also explain "detection".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Oh! I see, This is my first time hearing this name.  Thanks for the info. I'll dig a bit deep in that.